# How can I await a jquery function that returns a response from an ajax get?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, .net-core, get

I have a function that returns an ajax get response:

```
var myAjaxFunction = function () {
   $.get("/Page1/Index?handler=MyFunction",
        { itemId: itemId})
       .done(function (response) {
           return response;
        })
        .fail(function () {
            return null;
        });
}
```

This function is called and response is assigned to a variable.

```
var pendingOperation = myAjaxFunction();
```

Debugging, the problem that I'm seeing is that if I put a breakpoint on or after the pendingOperation line, it remains undefined. If I continue after the breakpoint, it then hits myAjaxFunction and I can see it tries to return a response containing data. By that point, it is already too late and pendingOperation is undefined. How can I guarantee that myAjaxFunction waits for the get/fetch of data and successfully returns my response before moving on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Your MyFunction must use .Wait() inside.

For example,

```
public IActionResult OnGetMyFunction(int itemId)
{
     var list = DoSomething().Wait();
     return list;
}
public async Task<List<Test>> DoSomething()
{
     //do something
}
```

It will wait until MyFunction is completed, then return back to MyAjaxFunction.